# Overwrite methods of specific instance attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a class `Invoice` which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. `Invoice` has an attribute called `tax`. What I want to do is, return a formatted string from the `to_s` method of the attribute `tax` that looks like `19,00 %`.

Now, how do I overwrite the `to_s` method of a instance attribute?

I know, that I can do this in a view with `number_with_precision` and I18n enabled, but I want the functionality in a central position. Which is the the `to_s` method of the attribute.

Is this the right way to accomplish this behavior or is there another way of getting this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overwrite the `to_s` method of attributes. What you *can* do is create a method in your Invoice model called `formatted_tax` like this:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def formatted_tax
    # do your formatting on self.tax here
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming their tax attribute is a decimal or float in the database, not a string, but this is still exactly what I would do.

Comment: Yes, thanks! That's what I do at the moment. But I thought it would be much nicer, if `to_s` returns my formatted string. @DylanMarkow: It is a `Float` coming from the database, you're right. I missed that out, sorry.

Comment: You can just rename `formatted_tax` into `to_s`, and do everything like in this answer.

Comment: @Flexoid that would change `to_s` for the entire `Invoice` object, not just the tax field.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, of course it's not a string. Anyway, the point is that you cannot overwrite the `to_s` method on an attribute. Not easily anyways. Besides, with `tax.to_s` it wouldn't be immediately clear that it returns a formatted string, whereas with `formatted_tax` it does. Therefore I think `formatted_tax` would be a better solution even if you *could* overwrite `to_s`.

Comment: What about doing a `Numeric.class_eval...` in a `def tax` method?

Comment: I don't know. Did you try? In my opinion you are just making your code harder to understand, without gaining anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After thinking about it, I will go with the `formatted_tax` variant. @Mischa Readability was my eye opener.